# Maths sum for javascript validation on form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Trying to create a very piece of validation to prevent spammers. I want a field with a label saying 'What's 2 + 7?' so the Javascript needs to know the result and pass the validation. I'm struggling to write this, would it be something along the lines of:

```
var valid = '';
var required =  ' is required';
var sum = $('form #sum').val();

if (sum == '9') {
    valid += '<p>An answer is' + required + '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that say `if (sum == '')`, indicating nothing has been entered?

Comment: Not sure. I think this is where I'm going wrong. How do I state what the answer 'should' be, and what to do if it's wrong?

Comment: @RichardJames  you could write a simple prevention based just on the javascript which will not be passed automatically by the bots, but without server-side check it could be bypassed manually by a person creating a specific posted data.

Comment: Also what if the user inputs 'nine' or '      9         '?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell exactly what's needed without looking at more code.

A simple question like this may very well work if it is generated server side and it is a lot better for accessibility than captchas. In order to be effective the question and answer should also be randomly selected.

You may chose to include a pre-submit client side validation for usability purposes, but since spam bots ignore JavaScript, it is useless to prevent them, unless you do something really complicated.

A bonus tip off topic: Your JQuery selector is inefficient. When using an id-selector you will never need to include its parent.

Comment: Thanks, will look into your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Client side validation via Javascript is not going to do much to guard against spammers.  Most spammers will have bots that don't even parse Javascript.

The only way to do this reliably is to handle it server side.

I would recommend trying something like Recaptcha: http://www.google.com/recaptcha

Comment: True, you should use some sort of captcha like reCaptcha.

Comment: Was trying to steer away from Captcha, as I've seen some sites implementing what i'm trying to do nicely, but I guess the consensus here is to not bother with client side validation.

Comment: @RichardJames Trying to validate it client side is only going to make it harder for legitimate posters to post.  It will not deter most spammers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is not going to answer your question per se but I want to suggest that you don't do this. Creating these spam preventions mechanisms is actually very complicated and your idea isn't really going to work if a spammer really wants to come after your site. I would suggest you look into a service called [recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha). It is free, easy to set up and the information entered by users is put to use digitizing old books.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in comments, you could prevent the bots from posting your data with just a javascript by itself. Let me explain how you could do it:

1. You could set initially the wrong or empty action for your form and later, with the help of javascript, set it to the correct one if the answer on the 'sum' was correct. Or even without the request for 'sum' as most of the spam-bots do not run js.
2. You could insert a hidden field named 'passed' with `false` initial
   value of it. Again, based on form interaction, you could set it to
   true and later check the data from the form (the value of this
   hidden field) on the server.
3. The last method, which I prefer in most cases, is to encode html
       code of your form with, for example, base64 and use your javascript
       to convert it back to HTML code. As soon as bots do not run js, they
       will not even know that you have a form on the page. The good part here is that you do not have to ask a person to enter something else in the form.

All these methods can be bypassed by a person interested in spamming on your website. He could check the final data sent to the server and create the set of the same requests to your server. That is why you need some server-side support in order to prevent you form even from manually crafted spam requests.

Comment: Thanks, sounds a little advanced for me but will look into it.

Comment: This does nothing to prevent me from sending posts using curl directly to the post url.  Spammers are not going to be using your actual form to submit, they will be using a tool that will directly post to your server side script.

Comment: @Jonathan  read the answer as the whole part! I wrote it in comments and in my answer. If your form would be INITIALLY incorrect then the bot, without usage of js, will not be able to submit a valid data!

Comment: Not necessarily... The spammer just needs to submit the form once, then they have the URL to post to.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Jonathan   I also wrote about that part. I showed the possible examples (which can be done by the pure js) and explained their weaknesses.